# Select2 - ability to search/filter values without Search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

Though it is already logged and discussed in below URL -
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3279

Now I want to know if below can be done?

1. The Search box is hidden from UI but is active in the background (not visible, like a hidden input).
2. User types on Select2 Dropdown (like default dropdown), the keyword goes to that search box and dropdown values filter.

And if it's not possible then is there any way where I can turn my all dropdowns in the site to normal html drodpown. Without impacting the code which is aligned to data coming from database and actions posting to server and vice versa, means coding aligned to span instead options tag.

It is important since one of my Client is looking to behave it like a normal dropdown.

Thanks for your time.